# In Google Sheets, can I copy a value to clipboard without its number/date/currency format?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell that is computed like `=A1+B1` (doesn't really matter but *it's a formula*) and this cell has a currency format on it, rendering the result as `$1,234.00`:

---

[image: Example Google Sheet]

---

Now pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> on the cell will put the string "$1,234.00" into my clipboard – when I paste it to other apps, it will contain the dollar sign and all the formatting:

---

[image: Pasted value in Google Docs]

---

Is there a way to copy just the **value** 1234 to clipboard? I know that within Google Sheets, I can do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (**Paste Special** > **Values Only**) but this only works within Sheets while my use case is to paste to other apps.

For example, in a Google Doc, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> will still paste "$1,234.00".

(My current workaround is to paste to some plain text editor, remove the formatting and copy to clipboard again. It's a bit annoying.)

Answer (score 0):

Use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) in cell `D1` to get the number without formatting in cell `E1`:

`={ "plain copy:", to_pure_number(C1) }`